# How add "active" class to open Bootstrap 3 accordion item?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I add "active" class to open Bootstrap 3 accordion item? In my example id adds "active" but does't remove from other elements. I'm using Bootstrap 3

```
<div class="panel-group accordions" id="accordion1">
    <div class="panel panel-custom">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                ....
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ... 
</div>


 jQuery('.accordions .panel-heading a[data-toggle="collapse"]').on('click', function () {   
    $('.accordions').find(jQuery('.panel-heading a[data-toggle="collapse"]')).removeClass('actives');
    $(this).addClass('actives');
 });
```

Comment: Is it active or actives (plural)? and btw, remove the jQuery wrapper here `find(jQuery('` find does the same

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove jQuery from this line of code:

```
$('.accordions').find(jQuery('.panel-heading a[data-toggle="collapse"]')).removeClass('actives');
```

---

Use like this:

```
$('.accordions').find('.panel-heading a[data-toggle="collapse"]').removeClass('actives');
```

---

You can also do like this:

```
jQuery('.accordions .panel-heading a[data-toggle="collapse"]').on('click', function () {   
    jQuery('.accordions .panel-heading a[data-toggle="collapse"]').removeClass('actives');
    $(this).addClass('actives');
 });
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Does not remove the class.